# App gives SecurityException when trying to access already created account after App update

Tags: android, accountmanager, securityexception, android-securityexception

App(version 1), created an account using AccountManager for saving auth tokens. Everything was working fine, was able to fetch and refresh Auth tokens

Sent out an update of the App (version 2), with no changes in the AccountManager code. I can see crashes for about 1% of my users.

Checked my code, no issue with authenticator xml or account constants.
My App is not on playstore, update is rolled out using amazon s3 .

The stack trace I see in Fabric is as below:-

```
10-04 19:28:03.484 E/AndroidRuntime(26436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 19:28:03.484 E/AndroidRuntime(26436): Process: com.xyz.com, PID: 26436
10-04 19:28:03.484 E/AndroidRuntime(26436): java.lang.SecurityException: 10551 caller uid  is different than the authenticator's uid
10-04 19:28:03.484 E/AndroidRuntime(26436):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1540)
10-04 19:28:03.484 E/AndroidRuntime(26436):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1493)
10-04 19:28:03.484 E/AndroidRuntime(26436):     at android.accounts.IAccountManager$Stub$Proxy.peekAuthToken(IAccountManager.java:904)
10-04 19:28:03.484 E/AndroidRuntime(26436):     at     android.accounts.AccountManager.peekAuthToken(AccountManager.java:838)*
```